# Native Query to JPQL conversion

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I need to convert the following native Query to an equivalent JQL

```
  <named-native-query name="proffering">
    <query>
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT po.OFFER_NAME, po.status,  pov.effective_from, pov.effective_to, pov.sales_start_date,  pov.sale_end_date,
          pl.product_line_name,  pl.product_line_id
        FROM offerTable po,  offerVersion pov,   offerProdLine pl,            
          (SELECT po.offer_id,    po.business_key business_key,     MAX(VERSION_ID) MAX_VERSION
          FROM offerTable po,    offerVersion pov
          WHERE po.offer_id = pov.offer_id
            AND (po.OFFER_NAME = ?1 OR ?1 IS NULL)
            AND (pov.PROD_LINE_ID = ?2 OR ?2 IS NULL )
            AND (?3 >= pov.sales_start_date)
            AND (?3 <= pov.sale_end_date OR pov.sale_end_date IS NULL )
          GROUP BY ( po.offer_id,    po.business_key  ) ) view1

        WHERE po.BUSINESS_KEY = view1.BUSINESS_KEY
        AND pov.VERSION_ID   = view1.MAX_VERSION
        AND po.OFFER_ID      = pov.OFFER_ID
        AND pov.PROD_LINE_ID = pl.offerProdLine_ID
        ]]>
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

Converted JPQL:

```
 SELECT NEW
        com.EntitySummary(
        po.name,  po.status,  
        pov.effectiveFromDate, pov.effectiveToDate, pov.salesAvailabalityStartDate, pov.salesAvailabalityEndDate,
        pl.name, pl.prodLineId)
    FROM   
      (SELECT po1.id, po1.businessKey businessKey, max(pov1.versionId) MAX_VERSION
      FROM pov1.prodOffer po1, ProductOfferingVersion pov1
      WHERE  (po1.name = ?1 or ?1 is null)
      AND (pov1.productLine.prodLineId = ?2 or ?2 is null)
      AND (?3 >= pov1.salesAvailabalityStartDate)
      AND (?3 <= pov1.salesAvailabalityEndDate OR ?3 IS NULL)
      GROUP BY (po1.id,    po1.businessKey)) view1 
      INNER JOIN ProductOfferingVersion pov on pov.versionId = view1.MAX_VERSION
      INNER JOIN pov.prodOffer po  on po.businessKey = view1.businessKey
      INNER JOIN pov.productLine pl
```

But, when I  deployed the ear in jboss-eap-6.2, it refused to 
recognize  "max" and   complained of an unexpected token '('

Comment: Sub-queries in the `FROM` clause are not supported.

Comment: @Tiny, Is the conversion possible?

Comment: If there is no alternative to rewrite the same query to **exclude** the sub-query in the `FROM` clause then, just stick to executing the native SQL query directly using `entityManager.createNativeQuery("Your native SQL");`. Only EclipseLink 2.4 or higher [supports](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause) sub-queries in the `FROM` clause (only JPQL but not criteria query) but it is still not defined in the specification. So currently it cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @Tiny, I've the offering & its version table with version specific attributes. I need to fetch the offerings with the latest version satisfying the supplied condition

Comment: I cannot envision whether or not the sub-select statement in the `FROM` clause can be excluded without looking into the table structure and other things. Try directly on the back-end system to reform the SQL statement to exclude the sub-select statement in the `FROM` clause. Sometimes, there exists some alternative/s to avoid sub-select statement/s in the `FROM` clause. If the sub-select statement in the `FROM` clause is however, obligatory then, there is no way other than executing the native query.